# How to select strings which don't contain letters in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column STR which may contain any strings. I'm using MySql. How to find strings which don't contain letters in SQL without using Regular Expressions? As I understand RegExp in SQL is [^...].
So how to select the strings without using [^...]?

Comment: actually I just need the idea

Comment: @Brien, I'm asking you because I can't find an answer and no one can provide it to me

Comment: Sure rdbms matters, else we don't know what string functions we are allowed to use. If you want to do this without regex there are different opions. You can check if binary upper is like binary lower or even use special functions like `SOUNDEX` which would return empty string if there is no letter in string: `SELECT * FROM \`my_tab\` WHERE SOUNDEX(\`my_col\`) = ''`

Comment: @bobblebubble and that SOUNDEX behaviour itself seems to differ according to implementation. In SQL Server it does not behave like that http://rextester.com/NKCMZ57423

Comment: You'll need to identify which character set you are using and which characters are letters of interest. For Unicode, there are 109591 letters. Even with a regex, that's a lot of separate ranges (unless your regex supports category classes). If you already have a regex, please give that.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp is the most sensible way of doing this. An alternative without...

```
SELECT STR 
FROM   YourTable 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   (SELECT 'A' AS C 
                           UNION ALL 
                           SELECT 'B' 
                           UNION ALL 
                           SELECT 'C'
                           /* Todo. Add remaining letters */
                           ) Chars 
                   WHERE  INSTR(STR, C) > 0)
```

Comment: what about hitting the system catalog to get a sequence and filtering the row number between 65 and 90 (and whatever the lowercase value is)...and converting that row number to a char?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 if MySql supported row number I might have gone that route but as far as I know you need to do ugly things with variables to simulate that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which RDBMS you're using. But, if you do not want to use regular expression, you can loop through every character in the string and check the ASCII code. If they are only falling in the range 48 to 57, they are only numbers.

Note : This may be very costly operation

Comment: What should the OP do if there are symbols?